# How to sort matrix diagonally

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

How to go from:

```
0 2 3
1 5 1
5 6 8
```

to

```
0 1 3
1 2 5
5 6 8
```

or something similar?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "diagonal sorting"? The example doesn't make it clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,20,(n,n))
a
# array([[10,  4,  6, 12,  6],
#        [ 5, 19,  1, 11,  5],
#        [ 6, 10, 11,  1,  2],
#        [ 5,  3,  0,  9,  1],
#        [13, 13,  3, 15,  3]])
io = np.argsort(sum(np.ogrid[:n,:n]).ravel())
out = np.empty_like(a)
out.ravel()[io] = np.sort(a.ravel())
out
# array([[ 0,  1,  1,  3,  6],
#        [ 1,  2,  3,  6, 10],
#        [ 3,  5,  6,  9, 11],
#        [ 4,  5, 10, 12, 13],
#        [ 5, 11, 13, 15, 19]])
```

We use `argsort` on the sum of the x and y indices (generated using `ogrid`) to establish the diagonal order. The sorted elements of `a` are then placed in this order using advanced indexing.